# unable to upload image file using go from minikube

Tags: docker, go

Below is my main.go file to upload images.
Here using this go file am building a docker image.
docker build is successful. 
On accessing the minikube service url, get options to upload, list and delete files. 
But once clicked on Upload file, get site cannot be reached.

```
var baseDirectory string
var ipaddress string

func main() {
    baseDirectory = "/usr/local/go/" // provide the base directory path where the files will be kept
    ipaddress = "localhost"          // provide the ip address of the webserver
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/uploadfile", uploadFile)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error occurred ", err)
    }
}
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var options [1]string

    options[0] = "</br><a href = \"http://" + ipaddress + ":80/uploadfile\">Click to upload file</a></br>"
    w.Header().Set("CONTENT-TYPE", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>%s</h1>, <div>%s</div>", "Home Page\n", options)
}

func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    //var s string
    if req.Method == http.MethodPost {
        f, handler, err := req.FormFile("usrfile")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "Error uploading file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        defer f.Close()
        filename := handler.Filename
        fmt.Println(filename)
        bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "Error reading file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(bs)
        err1 := ioutil.WriteFile(baseDirectory+filename, bs, 0644)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err1)
        }
        fmt.Println("Success!")
    }

    w.Header().Set("CONTENT-TYPE", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `<form action="/uploadfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload a file<br>
        <input type="file" name="usrfile"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>`)

}
```

Comment: Can i see your minikube deployment yamls?

Comment: yamls are present in this link https://github.com/prithika92/StoreImage

Comment: So you accessing it from your host machine using minikube ip, right?

Comment: yes.. this is my minikube url..
PS C:\Program Files_Mine\Kubernetes> minikube service image80-store --url
http://192.168.99.100:31385

Answer (score 0):

You hard coded `options[0] = "</br><a href = \"http://" + ipaddress + ":80/uploadfile\">Click to upload file</a></br>"` and `ipaddress = "localhost"`. But when you running it on minikube, it not accessible by `localhost`. I suggest to use relative path instead.

```
options[0] = "</br><a href = \"/uploadfile\">Click to upload file</a></br>"
```

Comment: @prithika nice. In stackoverflow if you find answer helpful, give an upvote.